# Promises cloud functions firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

I have some difficulties with a promise in cloud functions from Firebase.
I have this code:

```
exports.wantsToGoOnline = functions.database
    .ref('/groups/{groupId}/member_status/pending/{deviceId}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        const data = event.data.val(); 
        data.extra = process(event.params.deviceId);    

        const p = event.data.ref.parent.parent.child("online").child(event.params.deviceId).set(data)

        return Promise.all([p]).then(function(snaps) {
            return event.data.ref.parent.parent.child("pending").child(event.params.deviceId).set({})
        })
    })
```

I wait till a device is appended in the pending "key". I copy all the data to the data constant. Then I call the process method to obtain some extra info and append that to the extra key in the data array. But now the part, process can take up a while because it is a network request, how should I do that? Or is it already waiting?

Then I want to add the data to a new position in the realtime database. When that is done I want to remove the old info from the pending key in the realtime database.

So my question: the process method takes a while because it is a external network call, does the code wait there or do I need a promise? If so, how can I use the promise?

Comment: Your `process` method should also return a promise.  Use that to determine when the following work should execute.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the info! But now the question, how can I implement that?

Comment: you're returning from an event handler. that's not going to return to the variable you are defining.

Answer (score 0):

easy way for me to put your waiting code into a Promise

```
exports.wantsToGoOnline = functions.database
.ref('/groups/{groupId}/member_status/pending/{deviceId}')
.onCreate(event => {

return new Promise (
      (resolve, reject) =>{
        change.after.ref.parent.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
..
if(success)
  resolve("good")
else
  reject("its not good")
)
```